# How to extract one substring from one Java Object in python?

Tags: java, python

I've a String like this:  
["[Ljava.lang.Object;",[["Object0",{"key0": null, "coolKey1": "coolValue", "notCoolKey2":"something"}],["Object1",{"key3": "value1", "key4": "nonCoolValue", "Id":"importantId0", "someId":"importantId1"}],false,["Object3",{"key6": "value6", "nonkey7": "supercoolValue"}]]]    
what I'm interested is these two key-value pairs:  
Id:importantId0 and someId:importantId1 
How can I extract these two key value pairs from this String in ***Python***?

I've tried to use STRING.spit("DELIMITER"), but failed, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to be a JSON serialization and so you should use the `json` module to convert it to a Python object, then access the data you need from it.

```
import json

x = json.loads("""["[Ljava.lang.Object;",[["Object0",{"key0": null, "coolKey1": "coolValue", 
"notCoolKey2":"something"}],["Object1",{"key3": "value1", "key4": "nonCoolValue", 
"Id":"importantId0", "someId":"importantId1"}],false,["Object3", {"key6": "value6", 
"nonkey7": "supercoolValue"}]]]""")

print x[1][1][1]["Id"]
print x[1][1][1]["someId"]
```

Comment: This exactly does what I need, thanks a lot for teaching a rookie!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what these three indices 1 stand for respectively? Looks a very silly question, but I'm having trouble understanding it.